# Preparação de ambiente Android Cordova

Tags: android, node.js, apache-cordova

Seguindo o tutorial neste vídeo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4sYLBVGwxrw postado por Marcelo Costa, realizei todas as instalações conforme recomendado. Estou utilizando Windows 10. Instalei o Android Studio e consigo executar aplicações nativas sem problemas.

No entanto, me deparei com um erro persistente e continuo sem solução.

Executando o comando **cordova requirements** obtenho o seguinte:

> Requirements check results for android:
>
> Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
>
> Android SDK: installed true
>
> Android target: installed android-25,android-22,android-16
>
> Gradle: not installed
>
> Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android
>   Studio, or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please
>   include gradle in your path, or install Android Studio Error: Some of
>   requirements check failed

Segue abaixo algumas informações:

```
$ node -v
v6.11.2

$ cordoba -v
7.0.1

$ cordova emulate android

ANDROID_HOME=S:\Users\sandr\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144

Error: Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio,
or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please include gradle
in your path, or install Android Studio
```

[image: SDK Manager]